# Selective file restore for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, backup, restore

I created a backup of my old 12.04 installation before the computer died. I have a new computer and wish to get some files from that backup [on a local usb connected drive].

How do I get to select the files I want?

Comment: How was the backup created?

Comment: It was made with the Backup feature in 12.04. Looks like it was duplicity.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me that the Backup option on the standard desktop ought to provide that feature. Oh, well.